# convergence in distribution in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

We let $\Omega$ be a compact metric space and consider $C(\Omega)$ to be the space of all continuous functions on $\Omega$. The dual space of $C(\Omega)$ can be seen as the set of all signed borel measure on $\Omega$. My question is the following.

1. Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables on $C(\Omega)$, then there exists $X$ so, dass $\langle X_n,\mu\rangle\to\langle X,\mu\rangle$ in probability for every $\mu\in (C(\Omega))^*$
2. Let $\lambda_n$ be the distribution of $X_n$, then there exists a probability distribution $\lambda$ so, dass $ \lambda_n\circ\mu^{-1}\to\lambda\circ\mu^{-1}$ weakly for every $\mu\in (C(\Omega))^*$.

Are 1. and 2. equivalent?

Comment: How do you define the distribution of $X_n$? What is $\lambda_n \circ \mu^{-1}$? And in which space should converge $\lambda_n \circ \mu^{-1}$ weakly?

Comment: @gerw $\lambda_n$ is a probability measure which is also the distribution of $X_n$, $\lambda_n\circ\mu^{-1}$ is the composition of probability measures, and the convergence should be in $C(X)^*$

Comment: Maybe my notation is off, but the distribution of $X_n$ should be a measure of $C(X)$? What is $\mu^{-1}$ and how do you compose measures? Finally, the last convergence should be (almost surely) weak* in $C(X)^*$.

Comment: @gerw this are two statement of a theorem expressed in two different ways. The one uses the first assertion and the second the second assertion. I was trying to understand if these two statement are equivalent or not. All I have I wrote in the post.

Comment: Can you change your notation?  $X$ should not be a compact metric space and a random variable